# iframe parent window

Tags: iframe

I have an index.html page which contains an iframe into which all pages of the site are loaded. Has anybody a function (maybe javascript)? so that when you open Home.html via the google sitemap for example, it shows up in the parent frame in Index.html instead of opening by itself? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the `<head>`-section of your inner page:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

But note, this will open all of the links contained in the inner page in the parent page.

Comment: Thanks Remo, there is one small problem and that is that my Index.html page by default loads the Home.html page in the iframe. <iframe id="iframe" src="accueil.html" allowTransparency="true" name="iframeID" width="100" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="no">
   
   </iframe> so is there a way to over-ride this?

Comment: So it loads ``home.html`` instead of the defined src ``accueil.html``?

Comment: Sorry, accueil.html is home.html (but in french) I should have clarified. Your solution will work, say if I open contacts.html, it will load the parent page which is index.html, but straight away this page will load home.html in it because it is hard coded in the iframe tag. Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: So what do you want it to load initially? That's what the ``src`` attribute is for.

Comment: Hi remo, I'd like it to load home.html initially. This works, but if I use your solution, then say I open the page contact.html it'll then go on to load the index page (parent page) but with the home page in the iframe and not the contact page. I'm stuck...tried this in the head of each page but didn't work: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>try { if (top == self) {top.location.href='index.html'; } } catch(er) { } </SCRIPT>

Comment: Are you still in need of a solution? I'd have an idea.

Comment: Yes indeed I am... Have you found something? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, you have two files for each page, right? One that contains the iframe and one that contains the actual contents that should be loaded in the iframe. Right? If so, why don't you just change the 'src' of each page's iframe to match?